# Calling get_theme_setting from php-as-css file

Tags: theming

I'm developing a Drupal 7 theme, and I'm using a php file as my theme's css file, in order to be able to use variables to simplify colour changes across the entire css.

I've also defined some theme settings in the theme-settings.php

What I want is to be able to call get_theme_setting() from within my style.php file, and use the theme settings to determine CSS attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up implementing is embedding the PHP/CSS within the html.tpl.php file, as in inline style.

Comment: Just realised, I could have just pulled in the relevant settings in the html.tpl.php file, and sent them to the PHP-as-CSS file as GET arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to take a look to less css:

http://lesscss.org/

In fact there is a drupal module for this:

http://drupal.org/project/less

I used it a project and works great.

Comment: As fantastic as that is, I am still left with the problem of transferring variables from Drupal's settings to the CSS/Less file.